How to test urllib3 retry adapter for connection errors
my Retry class is
class RetryRequest:
    """
    Module for Retry logic on requests API requests
    """

    def __init__(self):
        # Retry Logic
        retry_server_errors = requests.adapters.Retry(
            total=20,
            connect=10,
            status_forcelist=list(range(500, 512)),
            status=10,
            backoff_factor=0.1,
            allowed_methods=['GET', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
        )
        adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_server_errors)
        s = requests.Session()
        s.mount("https://", adapter)
        s.mount("http://", adapter)
        self.session = s

my test is
@patch('requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter.send', side_effect=ConnectionError)
def test_retry_on_connection_error(mock_send):
    """
    Test to verify that the RetryRequest retries when a connection error occurs.
    """
    retry_request = RetryRequest()
    request_session = retry_request.session

    # Make the request and expect a ConnectionError
    with pytest.raises(ConnectionError):
        request_session.get('https://example.com/test')

    # Ensure that the request was retried 10 times
    assert mock_send.call_count == 10, "Expected 10 retries on connection error"

but it only gets called once, so the retry for 10 on connect is not working

I could not get it to trigger the connect retries, so not sure what that is. But I've settled for just using total. Anyway, I needed to raise inside urllib3.
@patch(
    'urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool._get_conn',
    side_effect=urllib3.exceptions.ConnectionError,
)
def test_retry_on_connection_error(m_get_conn):
    """Test to verify that the RetryRequest retries when a connection error occurs."""
    retry_request = RetryRequest(**{'backoff_factor': 0, 'total': 9})
    request_session = retry_request.session

    # Make the request and expect a ConnectionError
    with pytest.raises(requests.exceptions.ConnectionError):
        request_session.get('https://example.com/test')

    # Ensure that the request was retried 9 times
    assert m_get_conn.call_count == 10, 'Expected 9 retries on connection error'

